# New class Crashes app

Tags: java, android, class, android-toolbar

I created a new class for my toolbars edittext. I have it for expansion animation but it crashes when you click the edittext. Heres the code used

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
* Created by on 2018-01-07.
*/

public class Toolbar extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText search;

public void onEdit(){
    Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    search.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
}
}
```

personally ive never used other class rather one large class so any helpfull tips is greatly appreciated. The code in the MainActivity currently is blank which i was going to fill with webview once i got there or possibly in another class....

Here the crash data:

```
01-07 05:09:41.007 943-1130/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Does not handle dataspace request 
01-07 05:09:41.007 943-1130/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(3af0069:qcom.decoder.avc, ??(0x7f000062)) ERROR: UnsupportedSetting(0x80001019) 
01-07 05:09:41.009 943-2332/? E/OMX-VDEC-1080P: Does not handle dataspace request 
01-07 05:09:41.009 943-2332/? E/OMXNodeInstance: getConfig(3af0069:qcom.decoder.avc, ??(0x7f000062)) ERROR: UnsupportedSetting(0x80001019)
```

Comment: Add your crash log data.

Comment: Why extending `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: If you are creating an Activity you should register it in Manifest file.

Comment: Ive never used other classes, what would i put there

Comment: it is registered

Answer (score 0):

You can not find edittext because you have not set a view for this class, i guess you will be using this class from another activity which has ContentView and that is associated with an XML file. To be able to findviewbyids of that activity from this class. You will need to do something like this.

```
public class testclass {


        public void onEdit(Context context, Activity activity){
            EditText search;
            search = activity.findViewById(R.id.search_edt);


            Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0, -500, 1, 1);
            scaleAnimation.setDuration(750);
            scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            search.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        }

}
```

and from your main class call this class passing parameters of context and activity like this

```
a.onEdit(this,this);
```

now you will be able to retrieve the widgets of the UI of that activity from this class.

I hope i helped this explanation helped you.

Comment: I get and Error regarding "search=activity.findViewById(R.id.search) and "a.onEdit(this,this)"

Comment: replace "R.id.search" with your xml editText id. I gave id of search to my editText in XML file, you might have given a different name.

Comment: The error is in the "activity" and "a" for the main class

Comment: you have to make instance of edit class which is toolbar in your case.